# Aggregate function in BETWEEN and AND

Tags: mysql, sql

I have joined 3 tables in my query. In my Inventory db,Price is taken from table c and quantity is taken from table b. How can I show the records list of users who have ordered between the given value and maximum value of the column. 
I am using below query in mysql to retrieve records. As expected it shows error. Any help will be highly appreciated

```
SELECT .... GROUP BY userid HAVING  SUM(c.`price` * b.`quantity`) BETWEEN 9000 AND MAX(SUM(c.`price` * b.`quantity`))
```

Comment: What error it is showing?

Comment: Error Code: 1111
Invalid use of group function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you don't need `BETWEEN`. Try it this way

```
SELECT .... 
GROUP BY userid 
HAVING SUM(c.`price` * b.`quantity`) >= 9000
```

In case you wondered you can't chain aggregate functions. And even if you could it wouldn't make sense because you group by userid, but trying to get MAX of SUM from all users. In order for this to work you should've used a subquery to get max value e.g.

```
SELECT .... 
GROUP BY userid 
HAVING SUM(c.`price` * b.`quantity`) =
(
  SELECT MAX(total) total
    FROM
  (
    SELECT SUM(c.`price` * b.`quantity`) total
    GROUP BY userid 
  ) q
)
```

Comment: lolzzz.. Missed the easy way and trying everything else. Thanks buddy